# Python expression to find all dates in a database field that are between two dates

Tags: python, datetime, expression

I have built a python script that first prints all of last week's dates and then two variables are created that are the first and last dates so that I can then write an expression to find all of the dates in a field that are between those dates. Here is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy, sys, string, os, time, shutil, tempfile, logging, datetime
# this is the current date
now = datetime.datetime.now()

# subtract 7 days from the current date
SevenDaysBack = now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

# this is the date of the first day of last week
now_day_1 = SevenDaysBack - datetime.timedelta(days=now.weekday())

dates = {}
#this lists out all the dates of last week
for n_week in range(1):
    dates[n_week] = [(now_day_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=d+n_week*7)).strftime("%Y%m%d") for d in range(7)]
##for d in range(7):
    ##dates = [(now_day_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=d*7)).strftime("%Y%m%d")]
print dates

From_Date = dates[n_week][0]
To_Date = dates[n_week][6]
print From_Date
print To_Date

SaleDateExpression = [DATE_SOLD] "between" + From_Date + "and" + To_Date
print SaleDateExpression
```

The script works up until I try to create the Expression that will be used in a later function. I'm sure its a syntax issue but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: "I'm sure its a syntax issue ...", does it output any error when you try to run it? If so, please post the error it throws in full.

Comment: I can't get past the syntax error for it to run unless I comment out the expression. The rest of the script works. The syntax error highlights the word "between".

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an oddity in the second to last line:
`SaleDateExpression = [DATE_SOLD] "between" + From_Date + "and" + To_Date`.

The syntax error you are speaking of arises because `[DATE_SOLD]` as it is here is not valid Python; in addition, it seems to play no purpose, since you have not provided us with any information as to what `DATE_SOLD` is.

Thus, instead, the final line could be
`SaleDateExpression = [DATE_SOLD] "between" + From_Date + "and" + To_Date`
which would output

> between20161031and20161106

---

However, assuming that you want the output to be a bit more readable, there are a couple things to comment on.

Firstly, you are creating the dates as `%Y%m%d` which concatenates the year, month, and day together without spaces, creating the `20161031` and `20161106` you see; to potentially fix this, you could instead input `%Y %m %d` into `strftime`.

Secondly, there are no spaces between the words and the dates. In order to fix this, you could add a space after `between`, and before and after `and`, as follows `"between " + From_Date + " and " + To_Date`.

Finally, following all these instructions, your code will now output

> between 2016 10 31 and 2016 11 06

---

**Edit:**

Based off of your comment, it seems that the only problem was that `[DATE_SOLD]` was not within the quotations. To achieve the result you are looking for as posed in your comment being `[DATE_SOLD] between 20160601 and 20160630` you would need to utilize `%Y%m%d` in `strftime`, and add the spaces after the `between` and before and after the `and` as shown above. This would give the desired output.

> [DATE_SOLD] between 20160601 and 20160630

Comment: Thanks for the help Wintro. The expression originally came from a model I had built that does the same thing my script does. When I exported the model to a script the SaleDateExpression code looked like this: SaleDateExpression = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if SaleDateExpression == '#' or not SaleDateExpression:
    SaleDateExpression = "[DATE_SOLD] between 20160601 and 20160630" and the expression is called further down in a part of the script that isn't included. This one worked but I wanted to not have to edit the script before I run it each time so I replaced it with the code above

Comment: @ChristyWest I edited my question, was the issue resolved?